# Why can't I change the default set of filters for my reports?

Tags: business-objects

In SAP Businesse Objects InfoView - Web Intelligence everytime a user runs a report the values for the default filters are the same.

But in the last few months something has changed and the default values are not the same I published initially.

Seems like somebody has changed the report but I can't see this in the changing log. There is no change there.

How can I change those settings without saving a new version of the report? Is it possible?

I'm using SAP BO 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to save a *new* version of the report (using Save As). Just refresh the report, using your preferred settings, and then save it over the old one.